# Bluemix PHP Watson Personality Insights Service

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

What is the error in the code below? It returns this error:

```json
{ "error":"Internal server error (root cause: multipart\/form-data; boundary=----------------------------248f475465f9)",
  "code":404 }
```

Code:

```
<?php
     function testLangID($data) {
         $curl = curl_init();

         $headers_arr = array(
            "contentItems" =>  array(
                "userid" => "dummyuserid",
                "id" => "dummyid",
                "sourceid" => "freetext",
                "contenttype" => "application/json",
                "language" => "en",
                "content" => $data
            ) 
        );

         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $headers_arr);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "........:........");
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api");
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

         $result = curl_exec($curl); 

         curl_close($curl);

         $decoded = json_decode($result, true);

         return $result;
    }


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  
        $res= testLangID( $_POST["textLID"] ); 
        echo $res;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The url you are using:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api");
```

should be:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile");
```

I saw you are using `contentItems`, you can also sent `content-type: text/plain` and the `text` in the body no need to build the JSON object.
The curl command to send `text` in the body is:

```
curl -X POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD \
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
-d "Text to analyze" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile"
```

Comment: The answer is correct. If you are still having trouble, can you describe what your current problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I answered this in dwAnswers earlier this morning.

You only need the "body" parameter in the POST request (and "headers" if not using default value). As described in the API documentation the other parameters are part of the HTTP HEADER request.

Here is the PHP code modified to work with Watson Personality Insights:

```
     $curl = curl_init();
     $post_args = array(
          'body' => $data
     );
     $header_args = array(
         'Content-Type: text/plain',
         'Accept: application/json'
     );
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_args);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_args);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD,<user id>:<password>");
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api/v2/profile");
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     $result = curl_exec($curl);

     curl_close($curl);

     $decoded = json_decode($result, true);
```